# How to suppress the Redirect URI that appears in the user consent journey screen

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, authorization, linkedin-api

How to suppress the Redirect URI that appears in the user consent journey screen

[User consent journey with Redirect URI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROX6K.png)

Comment: Can I have some help from LinkedIN Support team please!!!

Comment: Want to comment that we want to remove the Redirect URI or replace it with a User friendly name like a company name. Need advice/help on how to do so.

Comment: See attached image file. Just want to replace or hide the Redirect URI (in our case is 'cb.9spokes.io') to a user friendly name like our client name.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look to possible. The OAuth authorization page layout is fixed and unless there's an option in [the developer portal](https://www.linkedin.com/developers) that allows you to change the way the redirect URL is displayed, there's nothing you can do about it.

Displaying the redirect URL on the OAuth authorization page is pretty standard and the most you could hope for is to be able to specify a label to be shown instead of the raw URL.